# Way to check if the same URL exists for another user in mySQL

Tags: mysql

First of all, let me explain the logic here. We have a table, which consists of articles added by users. Each user can add the same article more than once. We then have a "wall" (similar to Facebook), where it shows both their own articles + any of their "friends". Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ReadingListArticles` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id_fk` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `base_url` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image_path` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_id` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_source` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`),
  KEY `user_id_fk` (`user_id_fk`,`url`),
  KEY `image_id` (`image_id`),
  KEY `user_id_fk_2` (`user_id_fk`,`media_source`),
  KEY `media_source` (`media_source`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

The SQL is pretty simple:

```
SELECT * FROM ReadingListArticles WHERE 
user_id_fk IN ('their-username','friend1',,'friend2','etc')
AND base_url NOT IN ('list','of','sources','to','ignore') 
ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 20
```

This works just fine - but with one issue ... if they AND their friend have both shared the same article, it will show up 2 times on their list.

I'm wondering (pretty sure this must be possible, but I just don't know how :)) .... can we filter them out so:

- If the article exists by THEM (given priority), then show it
- If it DOESN'T exist by them, we can show it from any of their friends

Hopefully I've explained myself well, but please let me know if you need any more clarification.

**UPDATE:** I'm getting a little bit closer :)

```
SELECT * FROM ReadingListArticles WHERE user_id_fk IN ('test123','test2','designer1')
AND article_id > 0
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY article_id DESC
```

This works, but its getting the wrong record (it gets the latest one, which would only be correct if the current user were the last person to post that exact URL... but in reality this won't happen).  In my sample data, I have 2 records with the same "url":

```
url => http://wiadomosci.gazeta.pl
```

Then the *user_id_fk* varies:

- test123
- graphics1

The user who is requesting the data, is "test123"... so what we need to somehow do is prioritize that user_id_fk value when doing the *GROUP BY*, instead of just selecting the latest one to be added with that URL.

Anyone got any fresh ideas?

Thanks!

I'm now using (as suggested) the following query:

```
SELECT ReadingListArticles.* from 
(
 select max(article_id) as article_id
 from ReadingListArticles 
 where user_id_fk = 'Beata1234'
 and article_id > 170
 group by url
union
 select max(article_id) as article_id
 from ReadingListArticles 
 where user_id_fk IN ('Beata1234')
 and article_id > 170
 and not exists (SELECT 1
   from ReadingListArticles rla1
   where rla1.user_id_fk = 'Beata1234'
   and rla1.article_id > 170
   and rla1.url = ReadingListArticles.url)
 group by url
) q
join ReadingListArticles
on ReadingListArticles.article_id = q.article_id
order by ReadingListArticles.article_id desc
limit 20;
```

However, it has issues with the filtering. I have `article_id > 170`, but its still matching those with `article_id <= 170`. How can we fix this?

Comment: Might this help you out

`SELECT *,if(their-username.baseurl = friend1.baseurl,'high','low') as priority FROM ReadingListArticles WHERE 
user_id_fk IN ('their-username','friend1',,'friend2','etc')
AND base_url NOT IN ('list','of','sources','to','ignore') 
ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 20`

Comment: @AhmedKhan - Thanks for the reply. I'm confused about this bit: `if(their-username.baseurl = friend1.baseurl,'high','low')` ... what is that mean't to be? If I use this: `if(test123.url = designer1.url,'high','low')`, I get an error: "Unknown column 'test123.url' in 'field list'"

Comment: you just need to compare both the URLs of user and his friend than come up with priority. I don't know about your table that's why I made it like this

Comment: @AhmedKhan - unfortunately that doesn't help.. thats why I was asking ;) I included the table structure above - isn't that enough?  Thanks

Comment: have you tried COUNT?

`SELECT *,if(COUNT(base_url)>1,'high','low') as priority FROM ReadingListArticles WHERE user_id_fk IN ('their-username','friend1',,'friend2','etc') AND base_url NOT IN ('list','of','sources','to','ignore') ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 20`

Comment: @AhmedKhan - thanks. Not sure what the "count" would do though? We need to sort them in date order (not by the number of times it occurs), so not too sure what that would achieve :)

Comment: @AhmedKhan - I just posted some progress. Still can't get it to fully work though :(

Comment: As a pure punt: Have you tried using MySQL DISTINCT, you want to select DISTINCT urls so that each URL will only occur once in the output, regardless of source.

Comment: Your code should work with limit, so I am not sure what it is you think is not working. What do you expect? The result you will get is a list of distinct urls. The other columns will have values of random rows that have the given url and belong to any of your user in your list (if e.g. different products can be attached to the the same url, you will get a random product to that url, and you will get a random user from your list that has the url). Can you add the actual code you are trying (including the limit), the result you get and the result you expect? It's hard to guess what you want.

Comment: @Martin - yeah, the problem is that we need all the other data that goes along with it (in ReadingListArticles), so we can show the article + all its other info. So what we really need, is a way to tell the query to give a higher priority in the **GROUP BY**, when `user_id_fk = "test1234"`

Comment: @Solarflare - sorry about that. I have hopefully clarified it a bit above. Please let me know if you need any more info :) If its still not clear, maybe I'll give you an example schema + some sample data, so you can hopefully see what I'm seeing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to treat the main user and the other users differently, you can just split them up. With `article_id` being the only unique key in the table, you can use

```
SELECT ReadingListArticles.* from 
(
 select max(article_id) as article_id
 from ReadingListArticles 
 where user_id_fk = 'test123'
 and article_id > 0
 group by url
union
 select max(article_id) as article_id
 from ReadingListArticles 
 where user_id_fk IN ('test2','designer1')
 and article_id > 0
 and not exists (SELECT 1
   from ReadingListArticles rla1
   where rla1.user_id_fk = 'test123'
   and rla1.article_id > 0
   and rla1.url = ReadingListArticles.url)
 group by url
) q
join ReadingListArticles
on ReadingListArticles.article_id = q.article_id
order by ReadingListArticles.article_id desc
limit 20;
```

You might want to add an index on `url, user_id_fk`, but maybe `user_id_fk, url` is fine, depending on your data.

This will give you:

- The full row for all articles that user `test123` posted. If `test123` used an url several times, only the last article for this url will be chosen.
- The full row for all articles that `test2` and `designer1` posted, but which url `test123` hasn't have posted himself. If `test2` and `designer1` posted the same url, or if they posted the same url several times, only the last article of these is chosen.

Comment: you legend! That works like a charm :) For some reason it won't let me give the bounty for another 9 hours. I'll try and remember to come onto SO tomorrow, and post it to you. If I forget, please do remind me ;)

Comment: Ah actually, maybe its not working. If I use a different condition for article_id: `AND article_id < 170` (in both the places where we look at the article_id column) ... when I check the query in phpmyadmin, I get the exact same results again (even though the article_id for those is 170 and 171). Any ideas?

Comment: I've just updated my question, with a query I'm using, and having the issue with. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean? What results do you get exactly and what results don't you expect? The query with `and article_id > 170` will not give you any articles with id <= 170. It will treat them as if they were not in the database. Maybe that is what your problem is, you want to check older articles but not want to show them - that would belong outside of the union - so please be precise in what you expect. And by the way, the second 'Beata1234' should contain the friends (you don't need the union at all if they don't have friends - it will work though as it is).

Comment: thanks, that sorted it. Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Np. Btw, thanks for actually posting the code you used, it made it a lot easier. I often read stuff like "I did it exactly as you said, I just changed `article_id > 0` to `article_id > 170` and now it doesn't work as I want" and it takes a while to see the code ("Why do I need to post the code again? I used your code exactly right, I just made this little change to `> 170`. Must be something different!") to figure out small mistakes like that...